# Returns of running a batch file

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, output

My goal is to run a file, return its status (0 if success) and also return its output. I am using os module to have the status of running the simulation.

```
status= os.system("file")
```

And I am using subprocess module to have the output.

```
output=subprocess.check_output("file")
```

My question: Is there any function that enables me to have both status and output without running my file twice?

Comment: For windows you can check the status by checking the `%errorlevel%` system variable through `os.system()`

Comment: `subprocess.Popen` does that for you. (`wait()` for return status and `stdout` for output. Lots of examples of that here.

Answer (score 1):

`check_output` already does everything you need. From the docs:

> subprocess.check_output(args, *, stdin=None, stderr=None, shell=False,
>   universal_newlines=False) Run command with arguments and return its
>   output as a byte string.
>
> If the return code was non-zero it raises a CalledProcessError. The
>   CalledProcessError object will have the return code in the returncode
>   attribute and any output in the output attribute

So, if everything works well, it will just return the output. Otherwise, an exception is raised in which the exact return code is present as well as the partial output up to the error of the called process.